# Java-Getting the First and Last Record of the Similar Text from a Text File Based on a Given Input

Tags: java, search, text, timeline

I am having a deep confusion with the logic to design my code.

Let's say I have a text file like below:

```
Yong Ching Hong Sep 7,  2013 09:04:39  PM<br/>
Yong Ching Hong Sep 7,  2013 09:20:19  PM<br/>
Yong Ching Hong Sep 7,  2013 09:25:56  PM<br/>
Yong Ching Hong Sep 7,  2013 09:27:08  PM<br/>
Lee Kim Keong   May 30, 2014 09:33:34  AM<br/>
Lee Kim Keong   May 30, 2014 10:20:42 AM<br/>
Lee Kim Keong   May 30, 2014 10:23:47 AM<br/>
```

I want to get the first and last element of the text for a certain name. As you can see, the text has the same name with different timestamps, which are used to create a timeline chart.

Is there any possibility to search the string that could detect the specific group of lines that matches with my name and get the first and last element from it via *java*?

Thank  you, I appreciate your help and guidance.

Comment: Is the datafile sorted? What do you mean by "first and last element"?  (To me, the "first element" is "Yong Ching Hong Sep 7, 2013 9:04:39 PM", and the "last element" is "Lee Kim Keong May 30, 2014 10:23:47 AM.") Do you mean to select the first instance of a name, then the last instance of the same name?

Comment: Is it possible?  Absolutely.

Comment: @anorton Yes, that's what I'm actually try to convery. It means that I want to get the first record and last record of Yong Ching Hong, so the first record with this name should be "Yong Ching Hong Sep 7,  2013 09:04:39  PM" and Last Record of this name should be "Yong Ching Hong Sep 7,  2013 09:27:08  PM". This is the logic that I would like to code, but I can't really think of the actual flow of it.